# file with log4j logs is not created

Tags: java, xml, maven, log4j

searched, found nothing suitable, here is the config file in the folder resources:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
        
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\38096\\Desktop\\Directories\\logs
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

maven dependence :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

main code :

```
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            log.debug("Hello this is a debug message");
            log.info("Hello this is an info message");
```

IDEA output

```
2020-10-02 22:36:47 DEBUG Application:25 - Hello this is a debug message
2020-10-02 22:36:47 INFO  Application:26 - Hello this is an info message

Process finished with exit code 0
```

but no log file was created

tried to change dependencies, added different codes such as

```
static {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("D:\\intelliJIDEAProjects\\CRUDCOMPUTER\\src\\main\\resources\\log4j.properties");
    }
```

config file

```
log4j.rootLogger=file, stdout


log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\38096\\Desktop\\Directories\\logs
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

nothing helped, I suspect there is no write access, but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: It seems you're using log4j2. This has a different configuration file. The config file you are using is for log4j 1.X. Try changing the dependencies to use log4j 1.X or change the configuration file to match the log4j2 specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using log4j2. This has a different configuration file. The config file you are using is for log4j 1.X. Try changing the dependencies to use log4j 1.X or change the configuration file to match the log4j2 specifications.

(Note: This is from my original comment)